# error TS2339: Property 'handleError' does not exist on type 'HeroService' with Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

Alright guys, sorry about this question, as I know there are several already about Typescript when it compiles, but I'm encountering a flavor of this issue that I can't connect the dots with.

I'm trying to follow the Angular Tour of Heroes app, and am trying to finish it up with [the chapter on Http](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/toh-pt6.html), but my `hero.service.ts` file outputs this error:

```
error TS2339: Property 'handleError' does not exist on type 'HeroService'
```

I know from the other questions on here that this most likely has something to do with how Typescript is configured, but there does not seem to be a consistent cause of this issue.

I'm not familiar enough with the idiosyncrasies of Typescript (or Angular) to troubleshoot the issue on my own.

My code right now reads like this:

**CODE:**

```
import { Injectable }      from '@angular/core';
import { Headers, Http }   from '@angular/http';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { Hero }            from './hero';


@Injectable()
export class HeroService {
private heroesUrl: 'app/heroes'; //URL to web api

constructor(private http: Http) { }

getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
        .catch(this.handleError);
}

getHeroesSlowly(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return new Promise<Hero[]>(resolve =>
        setTimeout(resolve, 2000))
        .then(() => this.getHeroes());
}

getHero(id: number): Promise<Hero> {
    return this.getHeroes()
        .then(heroes => heroes.find(hero => hero.id === id));
  }
}
```

I am a bit puzzled by the fact that the error message says it can't find the property on 'HeroService' which is a class created within the program and is not a part of Typescript itself.

My `systemjs.config.js` file looks like this:

**SYSTEMJS.CONFIG:**

```
/**
* System configuration for Angular 2 samples
* Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
*/
(function (global) {
System.config({
paths: {
  // paths serve as alias
  'npm:': 'node_modules/'
},
// map tells the System loader where to look for things
map: {
  // our app is within the app folder
  app: 'app',
  // angular bundles
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
  '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
  '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
  '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
  '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
  '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
  // other libraries
  'rxjs':                       'npm:rxjs',
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular2-in-memory-web-api',
},
// packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
packages: {
  app: {
    main: './main.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  rxjs: {
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  'angular2-in-memory-web-api': {
    main: './index.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  }
}
});
})(this);
```

My `package.json` file reads like this:

**PACKAGE.JSON:**

```
{
"name": "angular2-quickstart",
"version": "1.0.0",
"scripts": {
"start": "tsc && concurrently \"npm run tsc:w\" \"npm run lite\" ",
"lite": "lite-server",
"postinstall": "typings install",
"tsc": "tsc",
"tsc:w": "tsc -w",
"typings": "typings"
},
"license": "ISC",
"dependencies": {
"@angular/common": "2.0.0",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.0",
"@angular/core": "2.0.0",
"@angular/forms": "2.0.0",
"@angular/http": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0",
"@angular/router": "3.0.0",
"@angular/upgrade": "2.0.0",
"core-js": "^2.4.1",
"reflect-metadata": "^0.1.3",
"rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
"systemjs": "0.19.27",
"zone.js": "^0.6.23",
"angular2-in-memory-web-api": "0.0.20",
"bootstrap": "^3.3.6"
},
"devDependencies": {
"concurrently": "^2.2.0",
"lite-server": "^2.2.2",
"typescript": "^2.0.2",
"typings":"^1.3.2"
}
}
```

If this question is a duplicate of some other version of this question that I'm not seeing feel free to direct me to it.

Thank you.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It was somewhat "mentioned" in the ToH tutorial, under the "Error Handling" part in the HTTP chapter. But it wasn't really clear that you needed to add this code part to your "hero.service.ts" file (at least if you tend to not fully read through text):

```
private handleError(error: any): Promise<any> {
    console.error('An error occurred', error); // for demo purposes only
    return Promise.reject(error.message || error);
 }
```

I just added it to the bottom inside the HeroService class and all worked. Hope it works for you as well :).

Comment: Thank you.  Yeah, I mostly go from code snippet to code snippet and then double check my results with their live examples as a way to pace myself through the exercise.  This helps a lot.

Comment: Glad I could help! I tend to do the same thing - which sometimes backfires :)

Comment: I was stuck at the exactly same part. 
However you are supposed to do the ToH step by step. It even mentions: "Refresh the browser, and the hero data should be successfully loaded from the mock server.".

The handleError method is introduced in the next part of the ToH. So this has to be an error.

Comment: I may want to add is has a GitHub Issue: https://github.com/angular/angular.io/issues/2808

Answer (score 4):

> Property 'handleError' does not exist on type 'HeroService'

Functions are properties also.

```
getHeroes(): Promise<Hero[]> {
    return this.http.get(this.heroesUrl)
        .toPromise()
        .then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
        .catch(this.handleError);  <=== Where is this? Not in HeroService
}
```

You need to define a `handleError` method in the `HeroService` class

```
handleError(error) {
  // do something with error
}
```

Looks like you missed [this part of the tutorial](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/server-communication.html#!#error-handling) :-)

Answer (score 1):

From the tutorial itself, you should add the following method to hero.service.ts

```
private handleError<T>(operation = 'operation', result?: T) {
    return (error: any): Observable<T> => {
      console.error(error);
      this.log(`${operation} failed: ${error.message}`);
      return of(result as T);
    }
}
```